# filter columns by by row contains string rule

Tags: pandas

I would like to filter dataframe by specifc row substring.
Below code output the expected dataframe by filter the column name, but my idea import pandas as pd

```
data = [
    ["A","Jack 001","Alice xyz","John","Jack xxx"],
    ["B",0,2,3,4],
    ["C",2,4,5,6],
    ["D",3,1,4,5]
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['v0','v1','v2','v3','v4'])
print(df)

df1 = df[['v1','v4']]
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  v0        v1         v2    v3        v4
0  A  Jack 001  Alice xyz  John  Jack xxx
1  B         0          2     3         4
2  C         2          4     5         6
3  D         3          1     4         5
         v1        v4
0  Jack 001  Jack xxx
1         0         4
2         2         6
3         3         5
```

is do not use columns name but use the row 1 substring contains "Jack".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `str.contains`

```
df1 = df.loc[:,df.iloc[0,].str.contains('Jack')]
Out[18]: 
         v1        v4
0  Jack 001  Jack xxx
1         0         4
2         2         6
3         3         5
```